# Spring Framework 5 Reference Documentation epub

Tags: spring

For Spring versions 5.x I cannot find any epub or pdf version of the reference documentation. Former versions were available e.g. at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/epub/. Are they available any more? epubs are perfect to be read with an ebook reader.

Comment: I've converted some of the asciidoc files myself from Github of version 5.1.x https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lk52-iojnVBsZFC4_CMO6vRXvseBUNAC?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that it will get published in time.

Meanwhile - this is the 5.0.4.RELEASE docs in pdf:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/

which you can convert to epub if you wish to do so.

**The only officially available and latest epub** is the 5.0.0.M5: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/5.0.0.M5/spring-framework-reference/epub/

Comment: Hopefully an epub version will get published. But I really do not believe this, as there are no other formats linked in the starting page, as it was with former versions. A converted pdf is not too good usable on an ebook reader. thx.

Comment: All the milestones of 5.0.0 have an epub version of the documentation. I expect that will be the case for the 5.0.x RELEASE versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

The epub for the latest version is not available.

but, I would recommend you to **try to convert the html documentation directly to epub.**
as converting pdf to epub does not result in very good result [as tools like calibre convert the pdf to html and then epub]

I tried a online converter to convert the https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/
and works pretty good.. [especially the code blocks seem better than the official epub]

hope you find this helpful.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried some online converters, but all of them convert only the starting page. i didn't find a one-page-html-version of the doc, which also has been provided in older versions. can you write which converter you used, or did you download the whole page tree with wget, as it is suggested elsewhere?

Comment: in 
`https://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-epub`
I entered the page link as
`https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html`
and click convert..
you will have to convert manually for each [core,web,Data access,Testing,etc.]

Comment: 2 of them I have converted:
core: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6x0bq7k5omgef4k/core.epub?dl=0
web: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uz12pfoy7o0sw2f/web.epub?dl=0

Comment: well, it seems it's not possible to download too many copies ... anyway, it works as described, if not choosing the root-URL, but the single "chapters", such as "core" which contains most of the stuff of the former ref doc. thank you very much, this helps indeed.